# How can I copy the text of a Button in the clipboard?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, clipboard

I have a simple button in my app:

```
<Button Content="{Binding ViewModel.Name}" Command="{Binding ViewModel.Command}"  MinWidth="50">
</Button>
```

I want that when you press right click in the button, the content (text) inside the button will be copied in the clipboard.

Can we do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since its binding to `ViewModel.Name`, just copy that into clipboard then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interactions to bind the MouseRightButtonUp event on button to the command on your view model. Interactions you can find in

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonUp">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CopyButtonText}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

you wil have to import interactivity namespace :

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.I‌​nteractivity"
```

Window.Interactivity namespace has EventTrigger and InvokeCommandAction.

and in the copybuttonTest command handler you can do

```
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, Name);
```

Comment: Which namespace is for  <utils:ExecuteCommand>? Thanks

Comment: here updated the answer.. hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

First get the button content,

```
string contntText =   btnName.Content.ToString();
```

Then set the text to clipboard,

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(contntText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Button to:

```
<Button Content="{Binding ViewModel.Name}" Command="{Binding ViewModel.Command}"  MinWidth="50">
    <Button.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="RightClick" Command="ViewModel.CopyToClipboard" />
    </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

In your `ViewModel` define the following method:

```
public void copyToClipboard() 
{
    System.Windows.Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, (Object)this.Name);
}
```

Then assign `copyToClipboard` method to `CopyToClipboard` command.